# Spyder Variable Explorer not showing pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas, variables, spyder

Example:

```
type(VARIABLE_something)
Out[1]: pandas.core.series.Series`
```

However, the Variable Explorer is empty. Nevertheless, other standard variables are there.

**Question:**

- is it my fault or is the expected behaviuor?
- is there something that I can do to visualize ALL variables?

Details:

- Spyder 4.1.5
- Python 3.8

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If your variable is called `VARIABLE` (i.e. all in capital letters), you need to go the options menu of the Variable Explorer (the one with three horizontal lines on its top right) and deactivate the option called `Exclude capitalized references` to see your variable.

Comment: Hi Carlos, `VARIABLE` was written only for this question purposes. It does not exist in my program. The name of the variable was `HW_X_16_8_p` that has a capital letter too at the begining. Does it affect?

Comment: Perhaps. Please try my suggestion to see if that helps.